# Safely casting away nullishness in typescript

Tags: typescript, casting, react-typescript

I'm looking for advice on better ways to deal with nullish values.

I'm currently learning Typescript. One of the problems I run into frequently is converting values that are potentially undefined or null to typed values that are neither undefined nor null.

e.g.

```
    currentTarget?: HTMLEement;

...
    let position = this.currentTarget.styles.position;
```

which of course produces an error because `currentTarget` is potentially `undefined`. Which is great. I get that.

Frequently, one knows by indirect means that a potentially null expression must not be null.  My preference would be to throw an error in this case, if the expression actually is null, rather than use null coalescing operators or guarding if statements to make the error go away. For example, I could write `someObject?.someProperty?.someMethod()` which makes the error go away; but it ignores the fact that it is almost always an error if any of those null coalescing operators have effect. It would be better (although impossible) to write `someObject.someProperty.someMethod()` and have an exception thrown.

I've taken to writing guard functions to get rid of nullishness. e.g.:

```
model?: Model;

getModel(): Model {
    if (!this.model) throw new StateError("Model is null.");
    return this.model;
}
```

and have contemplated the idea of:

```
function nullCast<T>(value: T | null | undefined): T {
   if (!value) throw new Error("Value is null");
   return value;
}
```

[edit: corrected the code for `nullCast` (which works amazingly well.]

There's nothing terribly awful about

```
if (!this.model) throw new StateError("Model is null");
... carry on with non-nullish model...
```

And I am gradually learning to provide default values for variable, even when they are of complex type, rather than declaring objects as nullish-able.

```
{
  model: SomeModel.EmptyModel();
     ... instead of ...
  model?: SomeModel;

}
```

But in the end, it seems like a non-negligble portion of my code is dealing with nullish-able variables that I know I know to be not nullish by virtue of the fact that the function I am in would not be executing if the program was in a state where those variables could have null or undefined values.

A compelling example currently at hand: a Model class that fetches initial state from a remote server via websocket. The initial state is populated asynchronously, during which time a "loading..." screen is displayed. This in turn forces the code implementing the UI to deal with null or undefined model properties which could not possibly be null if the UI is being displayed.

While I appreciate that it takes effort to be perfectly correct, I can't help thinking I'm missing better ways to deal with this. Advice on alternatives or best practices appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of [non-null assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)? If not, might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I would not recommend non-null assertions here. They can be quite dangerous. Many times I've used them to say this can't be null, only to deal with hard to diagnose bugs 6 months later because it turned out it really was null sometimes. IMHO, throwing an error is far more preferable.

Comment: @Connor Low: non-null assertion is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Save for the fact that they don't actually assert.

Comment: @Alex Wayne: Could you explain what the dangers are? x!.y seems pretty safe given that it will throw an exception in compiled javascript code. No need to explain why x.y! is dangerous. I can see the problem there.

Comment: @RobinDavies you have a point. But two things: 1. It's easy for the programmer to screw up because it allows you circumvent the runtime code that would be required to handle that otherwise nullish value. So in this case, it's probably fine if the null case is to throw an error. But if you aren't paying close attention and use it wrong, the typescript compiler won't help you. 2. The assertion is only good for that line, where if you check it properly, you're good for that whole scope. See https://tsplay.dev/N9JA7m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"For example, I could write `someObject?.someProperty?.someMethod()` which makes the error go away; but it ignores the fact that it is almost always an error if any of those null coalescing operators have effect."*

If having a null value there is an exceptional situation, then your types should not allow that null. It sounds like your types are too permissive. If it's an error when the value is `null`, then it stands to reason it should be a *type error* when the value is `null`.

Dealing with nullish values is something that we all have to deal with, but it's really hard to generalize about since what to do in the null case is very dependent on how your app/code works.

---

In general, when I have properties that need be non-null most of the time, I declare them as such.

```
interface MyType {
  someObject: {
    someProperty: {
      someMethod(): void
    }
  }
}
```

And then only make the fields optional when required for that circumstance:

```
function makeMyType(values: Partial<MyType>): MyType {
  return { ...defaultMyType, ...values }
}
```

Sometimes it can't really be avoided easily, and in this cases I do end up doing a lot this:

```
if (!foo) throw new Error('really expected foo to be here!')
console.log(foo.bar)
```

Or in some cases just:

```
if (!foo) return
console.log(foo.bar)
```

Which is fine. If it ever really is nullish, then you get a nice error message about what went went wrong. Or, in the second case, you just bail from a function that would be invalid in the null case.

---

It's hard to advise more specifically without the details of your types. But in the end if:

> *"it seems like a non-negligble portion of my code is dealing with nullish-able variables"*

then I would look at your types first to make sure you remove as much nullishness as you can.

---

Another option is to use a [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to validate whole objects which you can then use without testing every single property everywhere:

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string
  bar: string
  baz: string
}

function validateFoo(maybeFoo: Partial<Foo>): maybeFoo is Foo {
  return !!maybeFoo.foo && !!maybeFoo.bar && !!maybeFoo.baz
}

const partialFoo: Partial<Foo> = { bar: 'a,b,c' }
if (validateFoo(partialFoo)) {
  partialFoo.bar.split(',') // works
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYBcyAzmFKAOb7IBGcUpFVItBjAXi5TbgF9cuGAFcQCMMHQhkANzgAbYABM4kDOgAUAWzgBPehE2kACkylKAPJoB8ASlJ7DxzMmBk0bvASgQwolCyAITBzkaaAHREWABkscih4a7okYxQyPGJYQYRmGlwXILCCDIUyAAOFsBKJsjmUJaKNpi2yAC8OAxMpADkcAA09AMIvchCwDDIWgrKahqYWlWNNYqa9vY4dMtNUemRZBXKYFq9A72bAPSXyADu6FAA1mSCQA)

Comment: Helpful, thanks. Most of the problems revolve around complex chunks of data that are being populated asynchronously via websocket responses and notifications on a model object that wraps server communication internally.  The challenge is dealing with initial state of the model properties until the data gets filled in. It's not always straightforward to synthesize "empty" values for these complex types to serve as stand-ins until actual live data gets fetched for the first time. But I'm thinking that may be the way to go.

Comment: I see. Your explanation sounds similar to a problem I recently had as well. My solution was to validate partial object to see if they are whole, and only proceed if they are. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

I marked Alex Wayne's answer, above, as the accepted answer. It makes a lot of useful points about pain I've inflicted on myself.

But I'd like to take a moment to extol the virtues of `nullCast`, which has worked out far better than I expected.

```
function nullCast<TYPE>(value: TYPE | null | undefined) : TYPE
{
   if (!value) throw Error("Unexpected nullish value.");
   return value;
}
```

The principal beautify of nullCast is that one never needs to supply the template parameter. TypeScript will correctly infer the non-nullish return type automatically. This works.

```
  class Foo {
      optionalBarValue?: Bar;

      getBarValue() : Bar {
          // no explicit template parameter required.
          return nullCast(this.optionalBarValue); 
      }
  };
```

where "correct" means an exception will be thrown at runtime if `this.optionalBarValue` is undefined, and the automatically inferred return type of nullCast() at compile time is `Bar`, with any combination of `| null`, and `| undefined` stripped away.

Unlike the null-assertion operator '!' which produces no runtime code at all, nullCast does generate code, and does throw definitively. Compare

```
  let value: TYPE = this.objMember!.member!;
    // no effect at runtime'. An error is throw if .objMember 
    // evaluates to null or undefined, but no exception is thrown
    // if .member is nullish. The value variable ends up 
    // holding a value at runtime that is not of correct type.

   let value: TYPE = nullCast(this.objMember?.member);
     // Throws convincingly at runtime if either .objMember 
     // or .member evaluate to nullish. The inferred return type
     // of .member is non-nullish concrete type of .member.
```

There's nothing terribly wrong with using if statements to remove nullishness in following code. But it is intrusive, and has a negative effect on compactness and legibility. If your intention is to throw an error when nullish assumptions are violated, nullCast can be used compactly and efficiently inline when evaluating expressions, while still maintaining clear visiblity for readability purposes. e.g.:

```
let value1 = nullCast(this.member1);
let value2 = nullCast(this.member2.function()?.member);
```

or even (somewhat hesitantly)

```
let value = nullCast(this.function1)(arg1,arg2);
```

Motivation: One still needs to evaluate on a case-by-case basis what the correct response to a nullish value is. But the brutal easiness of `if (!value) return;`    makes it far too easy to do the wrong thing. If a nullish value violates an assumption in code, the correct response is to throw at runtime, rather than return without regard for the delayed consequences of not doing what should have been done. nullCast, in certain cases, makes it easier to do the right thing.

Anyway. Back to doing my homework on type predicates.